# Python: Trying to Count Number of 1 Bits in an Integer But Missing One 1

Tags: python, function, count, bit

```
Input: n = 00000000000000000000000000001011
Output: 3
Explanation: The input binary string 00000000000000000000000000001011 has a total of three '1' bits.
```

When I run my code below it appears that only two 1's are recognized ... why is that?

```
class Solution(object):
    def hammingWeight(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        
        sum = 0
        
        for i in str(n):
            sum += int(i)
            
        return sum
```

[image]

I think I'm misunderstanding some concepts here.  Would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: What do you see if you add `print(n)` and `print(str(n))` to your code? Does this give you a clue as to what is wrong with your solution? Hint: what base does `print()` and `str()` use to convert an int for display?

Comment: The binary number `0b1011` is `11` in base-10. The integer `n` is 11. If you take the base-10 integer 11, turn it into a string, and count the 1s, there are two 1s.

Comment: @PineNuts0 there are several ways you could do this, the simplest probably being using `bin` to convert a base-10 integer into a base-2 representation, and counting the 1s in the resulting string.

Comment: @PaulM. Nah, looks like LeetCode, which has Python 3.10.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'm unclear, what did you think I meant?

Comment: @PaulM.`bin(n).count('1')`.

Comment: Yup, you're right, that's far more efficient. Comment deleted...

Comment: @KellyBundy `n.bit_count()`?

Comment: @Nick Yep, that.

Comment: @KellyBundy lucky LeetCode keep their python up to date! :)

Comment: @Nick Yeah that's nice. Usually I test SO stuff on TIO.run but a few times when I needed newer Python I abused LeetCode for it.

Answer (score 1):

Python `3.10` introduces [int.bit_count()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) but if you have to implement the algorithm yourself then you can try something like this:

**test.py:**

```
def count(n):
    bits = 0

    while n:
        bits += 1
        n &= n - 1

    return bits


def main():
    n = 0b110001010000000000111
    c = count(n)

    print(f"Bit length: {n.bit_length()}, bits: {c}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
Bit length: 21, bits: 7
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(k)` where `k` is the number of bits set to 1.

Comment: "O(k)" is a bit of a couldnt-make-up-my-mind analysis. If you assume n is a fixed-size int, you can say it's O(1), and if you assume it's arbitrary-size, then you're not O(k) but O(k log n).

Comment: I don’t agree, even with a fixed-size int it doesn’t take a constant number of steps, for instance `0b11111111` vs. `0b10000000`

Comment: I didn't say it takes a constant number of steps. That's not what O(1) means. It means it's *bounded* by a constant, and only that it does from some point onwards. You're confusing ≤ with = and n₀ with 0.

Answer (score 0):

change `str(n)` into `bin(n)[2:]`. This way you will get binary representation string of `n` with omitted "0b" prefix.

BTW, you don't need to count manually in a loop. Python string has `.count()`:

```py
return bin(n).count("1")
```